# How to search from list ObjectID in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a "ClubFollower" schema like below:

```
const ClubFollower = new Schema({
    id_club:{
        required:true,
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        unique:true
    },
    followers:[
        {
            _id:false,
            id_follower:ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxx"),
            follower_type:String // 'club' | 'user'
        }
    ]
});
```

each follower has many information such as:name, phone, email , etc...  the question is how do I search a follower by name, phone, email ... with this schema. I dont think loop all item in follower array then `findById` with each `id_follower` and compare search key with email, phone... is good solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). First you [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) on `id_club`, then you [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `followers` and [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) followers from their collection based on `id_follower`. Finally, you can use other stages to filter based on followers'  attributes.

You could also search from the other side. Have your `followers` collection store the clubs they are part of and match against that collection instead.